# Paypal's Address Saved As Default Address

Tags: magento-1, paypal, address, billing, default

A new customer who makes a virtual product purchase through paypal has their billing address passed to Magento.  The address is attached to the order but is not attached to the customer.  What would be the best way to attach this to the customer and also set it as the default billing address on their account?

Comment: I am not aware of such built in capability, so best bet is custom module. I guess what you ask for is only option with PayPal Express

Comment: It looks like this needs to be coded as an additional extension. The paypal module does not have many events to work with but it does have

    paypal_payment_transaction_load_by_txn_id_after

At least for paypal standard this looks to be triggered when an IPN notification is received. In the observer you can access the transaction

$paymentTransaction = $observer->getEvent()->getPaypalPaymentTransaction();
$orderPayment = $paymentTransaction->getOrderPaymentObject(); This should hopefully get you close enough to the order object and you can start testing if the customer has a billing address.

Comment: Did you get an answer? Did @fooman helped you? Then write the answer down fooman and Ryan can accept it - if it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to tap into the `predispatch` event of the `Mage_Paypal_IpnController` class:

Create the xml in your custom module to handle the observer for the predispatch:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_paypal_ipn_index>
            <observers>
                <mymodule_paypal_ipn_index>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>yourmodel/observer</class>
                    <method>ipnPreDispatch</method>
                </mymodule_paypal_ipn_index>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_paypal_ipn_index>
    </events>
</global>
```

Observer.php:

```
<?php

class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{

    public function ipnPreDispatch($observer)
    {
        //get the request object and post data
        $data = $observer->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getPost();

        //get the email address
        $email = $data['email_address'];

        //get the customer via the email
        $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->loadByEmail($email);

        //set the customer default address
        $default_address = array (
            'firstname' => $data['first'],
            'lastname' => $data['last'],
            'street' => array (
                '0' => $data['street1'],
                '1' => $data['street2'],
            ),
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'region_id' => $data['state'],
            'postcode' => $data['zipcode'],
            'country_id' => $data['country'],
            'telephone' => $data['telephone'],
        );
        $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');

        $address->setData($default_address)
                    ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                    ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
                    ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
                    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
        try {
            $address->save();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            Mage::logExeption($e);
        }

    }

}
```

I'm **not certain of the format of the IPN**, so the keys of `$data` in the observer above **may need to be altered** to adjust. Also, I'm **not sure of the business rules**, so at the moment it sets **all IPN customer addresses** to the default to whatever was on their most recent order. This is **not production-ready**, but gets you 90% of the way there.

Comment: Hooking into the controller_action_predispatch_paypal_ipn_index observer did the trick.  Thank you for this valuable information!

Comment: Fooman deserves a lot of credit here. Cheers!